How to performantly submit messages of arbitrary size (and fields) to a common interface?
I have a message processing interface that accepts messages of different types. What I have now goes along the lines of this:
Demo
#include <iostream>

enum class MsgType
{
    write,
    read,
    reg_channel,
    unreg_channel,
};

struct Message
{
   MsgType type;
   union
   {
        struct
        {
            void* addr;
            size_t count;
        } write;
        struct
        {
            void* addr;
            size_t count;
        } read;
        struct
        {
            int fd;
            void* addr;
            size_t count;
        } reg_channel;
        struct
        {
            int fd;
        } unreg_channel;
   }; 
};

struct SomeInterface
{
    auto submit(Message& cmd)
    {
        switch(cmd.type)
        {
            case MsgType::write:
                std::cout << "write command submitted" << std::endl;
                break;
            case MsgType::read:
                std::cout << "read command submitted" << std::endl;
                break;
            case MsgType::reg_channel:
                std::cout << "reg_channel command submitted" << std::endl;
                break;
            case MsgType::unreg_channel:
                std::cout << "unreg_channel command submitted" << std::endl;
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    SomeInterface iface;

    std::byte b;
    auto cmd = Message{
        .type = MsgType::write,
        .write = {
            .addr = &b,
            .count = 1024,
        },
    };
    iface.submit(cmd);
}

The problem with this approach is, that I don't get initialization or destruction of members. E.g. I wanted to insert an std::promise into specific commands, but it's not trivially constructible and destructible. So I would have to go through the hassle to implement a custom constructor and destructor, which takes away from the nice designated initialization (in main) which would not be possible anymore.
I could use an std::variant to handle this for me, the problem is that std::visit incurrs an unnecessary performance overhead and this code really sits in a bottleneck area that is used by multiple threads (mutexes left out for clarity), so I'm not necessarily fan of integrating degrading changes for the sake of convenience. Is there a best of both worlds?

Premature optimization is the mother of evil. You need focus on your synchronization problems first. std::visit should be the last amongst your concerns. It is of course possible to reimplement std::variant, if you need, but that comes after the benchmarks prove it to be worth the trouble; There are just too many technicalities to consider.

So you're essentially asking how to implement std::variant better than standard libraries. Good luck I guess?

If you don't like visit, you can implement a similar switch over variant::index()
